# ActiveRecord Class Methods / Relations self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am writing some rails code that uses proxy objects around ActiveRecord models. However, whenever a Class Method is called on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` or `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`, the value of `self` is the original ActiveRecord class as opposed to the relation. For example:

```
class Blah < ActiveRecord::Base   
  def self.thing
    MyProxyObject.new(self)
  end
end

Blah.thing #<MyProxyObject @wrapped=Blah>

Blah.where(:column => 'value').thing #<MyProxyObject @wrapped=ActiveRecord::Relation>
```

Desired functionality would be that the wrapped object in the second case would be the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object returned by `Blah.where`. Is there an easy way of achieving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
class Blah < ActiveRecord::Base   
  def self.thing
    MyProxyObject.new(all)
  end
end
```

works for me (prior to rails 4, use `scoped` rather than all):

```
Blah.where(:foo => 1).thing
```

results in the proxy object holding a relation with the appropriate conditions applied.

Comment: I think it is the best approach possible, but for `Blah.thing` it will wrap relation instead of class - which is not what OP wants. However for me it is pretty clear that wrapping a class would be a mistake, so +1.

Comment: @Frederick appears to be a mind reader, I didn't proof read my question, I did want the proxy object to wrap the relation but that was not reflected in the example code. This is exactly what I was looking for cheers.

Answer (score 1):

@FrederickCheung answer is the Right Way To Go. I post this answer to explain why it is happenning.

The mystery sits in `active_record/relation/delegation.rb` file:

```
def self.delegate_to_scoped_klass(method)
  if method.to_s =~ /\A[a-zA-Z_]\w*[!?]?\z/
    module_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
      def #{method}(*args, &block)
        scoping { @klass.#{method}(*args, &block) }
      end
    RUBY
  else
    module_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
      def #{method}(*args, &block)
        scoping { @klass.send(#{method.inspect}, *args, &block) }
      end
    RUBY
  end
end
```

As you can see it defines a new method on the relation object, which is just delegating it to the class, hence `self` is always a class itself here.

Answer (score 0):

Have found a hackish way of doing this, I will leave this unaccepted for a while on the off chance that someone will come up with a more elegant solution.

```
ActiveRecord::Relation.instance_eval do 
  def thing
    if klass.respond_to? :thing
      MyProxyObject.new(self)
    else
      raise NoMethodError.new
    end
  end
end
```

This just adds the method to the `ActiveRecord::Relation` class (in practice this should also be defined for `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` and `ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation`). It checks to see if the base class has the method defined, and if so creates the proxy object wrapped around itself instead